# how  to  navigate   for  a  new window[IE]   using datalist control

Tags: asp.net

i using a datalist control i am  binding  with hyperlink control

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="lbURL" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("URL") %>' />
```

so now this  hyperlink   would  contain an  url  that points  to  some web site  so once user  click on this link  a new  **IE**  window  should be  opened like if the url  contains" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", yahoo.com  any thing like  is
  so once user  clicks  open  the web site

any help  would be great . looking forward  for a  solution 
 thank  you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `target="_blank"` option.

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="lbURL" runat="server" target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
```

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp) reference

Comment: hey tried that but   still same issue
  now my  current  url  of the appliacation is like  this  url :abc.com/images/asdsad34343
  now 
<asp:Hyperlink ID="lbURL" runat="server" target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>' /> 
 text contains: www.asp.net
 when user  click the  hyperlink burron 
  in the url it  
becomes like this
 :abc.com/images/asdsad34343/www.asp.net
  so how  to solve this issue